# Return friendlier response body when an invalid API Gateway endpoint is requested

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework, lambda-authorizer

I'm using the [Serverless framework](https://serverless.com/) to create an API. Endpoints are defined in the serverless.yml file, creating API Gateway endpoints that route through a custom Authorizer function and resolve to Go Lambda functions.

However, if a client hits an endpoint that has not been explicitly defined, passing in their JWT Token in the `Authorization` header, API Gateway returns a `403 Forbidden` response with the following body:

```
{
  "message": "'{{JWT TOKEN}}' not a valid key=value pair (missing equal-sign) in Authorization header: 'Bearer {{JWT TOKEN}}'"
}
```

The `403 Forbidden` status seems appropriate, but I'd like to send an easier to understand error message back to my clients in the body of the response.

Is there a way to modify the response body when an invalid endpoint is requested?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the Serverless Framework does not support customizing API Gateway default responses natively (yet).
There is an [existing issue](https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues/3896) in the repository, if you are interested in following it.

For now, you will have to use CloudFormation to achieve this. There are a [number of options](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/api-reference/resource/gateway-response/) you can use to [customize error responses](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/customize-gateway-responses.html).
You will want to know specifically what [ResponseType](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/supported-gateway-response-types.html) you want to change.

For your use case, it looks like the `MISSING_AUTHENTICATION_TOKEN` Response Type is what you are looking for.
This is an example you can adapt and add to your `serverless.yml` (via the [`resources`](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/resources/) section):

```
resources:
  Resources:
    MissingAuthenticationTokenGatewayResponse: # Custom name, you can change it
      Type: 'AWS::ApiGateway::GatewayResponse'
      Properties:
        ResponseType: MISSING_AUTHENTICATION_TOKEN # The Response Type to customize
        RestApiId:
          Ref: 'ApiGatewayRestApi'
        StatusCode: '403' # The returned HTTP code
        ResponseParameters:
          # Set CORS
          gatewayresponse.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "'*'"
          gatewayresponse.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "'*'"
        ResponseTemplates:
          application/json: |
            {
              "error": "$context.authorizer.customErrorMessage"
            }
```

In `ResponseTemplates`, you can set the JSON output as you see fit.
This example simply set an `error` property, which will contain the value of the property `customErrorMessage` of the Lambda authorizer output `context` property.
You can learn more about this [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-lambda-authorizer-output.html).
You can also set it to be a static string if you want to, but being able to dynamically change the error message in your code is rather nice.